# Combining random elements of multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

In Ruby, how would I select a random element from one array and combine it with a randomly selected element from a second array?

For example if I have the arrays:

```
    array1 = ["x", "y", "z"]
    array2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I'm looking for the output to be (array1_element)(array2_element)(array1_element) like xby or ycz or xbx so on and so forth. Can Ruby's .sample method be used on multiple arrays to print out a single string?

Comment: `"#{array1.sample}#{array2.sample}#{array1.sample}"`

Comment: How can you, "select a random element from one array and combine it with a randomly selected element from a second array" to produce "xby"? Are you saying you want to randomly select an element from the first array, then randomly select an element from the second array and then randomly select a third element from the first array?

Comment: If you are sampling repeatedly you could construct an array of all (`3^3=27`) combinations and then sample from it: `arr = array1.product(array2, array1).map(&:join) #=> ["xax", "xay", "xaz", "xbx", "xby", "xbz", "xcx", "xcy", "xcz", "yax", "yay", "yaz", "ybx", "yby", "ybz", "ycx", "ycy", "ycz", "zax", "zay", "zaz", "zbx", "zby", "zbz", "zcx", "zcy", "zcz"]; arr.sample #=> => "zcx"; arr.sample #=> "yay" `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

**1)** You can use `sample` method.

```
array1.sample #=> return a random element from the array.
```

Then you can use string interpolation like

```
result = "#{array1.sample}#{array2.sample}#{array3.sample}" #=> ie "xby"
```

**2)** You can generate random index values

```
array1[rand(array1.length)]
```

This will generate a random index from `0` to `length-1` and call the `[]` method on the array. You can then use string interpolation as well.

**3)** You can use the `shuffle` method then `first` method

```
array1.shuffle.first
```

`shuffle` will, well, shuffle the array, and you can just return the first element.

I'm just listing the few I can come up with off the top of my head. There are probably tons of other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(array1 + array2).sample(3)   # => ["b", "x", "a"]
```

if you want your answer in array form, or

```
(array1 + array2).sample(3).join('')   # => "zxb"
```

if you want it in string form?

If the order is supposed to explicitly be `[array1_elt, array2_elt, array1_elt]` and you don't want any element repeated, then the following should do the trick:

```
array1.sample(2).insert(1, array2.sample)
```

Again, append `.join('')` to stringify the result.

Comment: this won't work all the time. OP wanted a specific order `(array1)(array2)(array1)`. You method will just return random 3 elements from the combined array, so you can result in `bzx`, which is the wrong order.

Comment: It wasn't clear that OP wanted specific order all the time, it came across as a "fer instance..."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to form an array `[a,b,c]`, where `a` and `c` are randomly selected from the first array and `b` is randomly selected from the second array, and then join the three elements of the array into a string.

If you are sampling repeatedly it might be worthwhile to construct an array of all (`3^3=27`) combinations and then sample from that array:

```
arr = array1.product(array2, array1).map(&:join)
  #=> ["xax", "xay", "xaz", "xbx", "xby", "xbz", "xcx", "xcy", "xcz",
  #    "yax", "yay", "yaz", "ybx", "yby", "ybz", "ycx", "ycy", "ycz",
  #    "zax", "zay", "zaz", "zbx", "zby", "zbz", "zcx", "zcy", "zcz"]

arr.sample #=> "zcx"
arr.sample #=> "yay"
arr.sample #=> "ycz" 
arr.sample #=> "xby"
```